# react router showing blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

Whenever I use BrowserRouter my page converts into blank white page. I tried to reinstall react-router and react-router-dom but still problem not solving.
I am using this versions:
react-router-dom@6.2.1
react-router@6.2.1

Please look at my code and tell me if there is any mistake in the code.

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Bookkeeper!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tempapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include your index.html

Comment: @adambcomer Done. added index.html in the post

Comment: refer a tutorial of how routing is done, your code is incomplete,

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code you just don't know how exactly to use react-router-dom

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. I created a new create-react-app project and copied in your code. It builds and renders the App component.

Comment: @DariushStony They is trying to follow the first step in the [react-router tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial). This code is copied from there.

Comment: @adambcomer yes I copied the exact code and followed the exact same steps but I don't know why this is not working in my pc.

Comment: My only guess is that you need to restart the dev server and update your packages. `npm update` then `npm start`.

Comment: There's no mistake/error in the code you've shared. I can't reproduce. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-showing-blank-page-uscpb). Is this ***all*** of your code? Is there any other relevant code you've not shared? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Are you seeing any errors in the console/terminal? You're not rendering any routes so it's not like you're just on the wrong path, `App` renders regardless. Try killing/restarting any code watchers/hot reloaders/etc.

Comment: @DrewReese The problem was in package.json file. I copied my package.json to your codesandbox directory and code gave error. I added package.json code in the post. Please tell me what was the problem.

Comment: Your package.json file is missing the `react-router-dom` dependency. Run `npm i -s react-router-dom` to add ***and*** save it to your package.json file. I've also not had any luck running any sandboxes with the `web-vitals` package, so you may've been seeing an error there, otherwise when I copied your package.json file into the CSB and removed `web-vitals` it prompted to add/install `react-router-dom` since it was missing.

Comment: @DrewReese Sorry my mistake I installed react-router-dom outside of my project directory without changing the directory. I am stupid. This was my first time creating a react project.

Comment: All is resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing react-router-dom into your project by
`npm i react-router-dom`

such that your package.json file looks like this

```
{ 
  "name": "tempapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
  "react-app",
  "react-app/jest"
 ]
},
 "browserslist": {
"production": [
  ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
  "last 1 chrome version",
  "last 1 firefox version",
  "last 1 safari version"
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your App component inside a Route.

It, should look like this:

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<App />}
    <Routes/>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: Also verify the render function, not sure if it works like this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).